# perform 3 javascript functions on single button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using 3 javascript functions for textfield validation,

1. validate all the fields once all the fields are properly entered
2. yes/cancel confirmation should be also along with a 
   pop up window with the textfilled values which are display in a pageto verify entered values are correct
   Once i select yes my button click event should occur if no is selected nothing sholud happen. pop up window can be closed by the user

Here is my js script,

I am getting all my textfields validated and  getting confirmation box yes/cancel but popup window page is not displaying

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function UserDetailsConfirmation() {
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to add this ?");
    return openwin();
}

function openwin() {
   window.open('PopupForConfirm.aspx?name1=' + name + '&age1=' + age + '&gen=' + gender + '', 'open_window', ' width=640, height=480, left=0, top=0');
}
function validate() {

    var name= document.getElementById('<%=this.txtname.ClientID %>');
    var age= document.getElementById('<%=this.txtage.ClientID %>');
    var gender= document.getElementById('<%=this.txtgender.ClientID %>');

    if (name.value) == "") {
        alert("Please Enter Name");
        name.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if (age.value) == "") {
        alert("Please Enter age");
        age.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if (gender.value) == "") {
    alert("Please enter gender");
    gender.focus();
    return false;
    }

else if (!UserDetailsConfirmation()) {
    return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just a notice; using javascript as validation isn't good, because user can edit the javascript on his browser.

Comment: for that i have also done a server side validation so no worries

Comment: Assuming you're using asp.net webforms and not MVC, use ASP.nets validation controls, often a better experience than `alerts`. I would also skip the pop up confimration. Have the page submit to itself, hide the form and show a `asp:panel` with the entered data. If yes is clicked do you data base stuff, if no/cancel, hide the asp:panel and reshow the form, all the data should still be there. Plan B would be have an "Inpage" confirm using JQuery or similar.

Comment: Example of inpage confirm using the ASP.net ajax tool kits modal popup extneder: http://nickstips.wordpress.com/2010/07/12/asp-net-ajax-modalpopup-to-confirm-delete/

Comment: And do you realy need to be getting your users to confirm twice?!

Answer (score 0):

You return right before you call openwin. How could it be reached? How about:

```
function UserDetailsConfirmation() {
  return confirm("Are you sure you want to add this ?") && openwin();
}
```

BTW:

```
if (!UserDetailsConfirmation()) {
  return false;
}
else {
  return true;
}
```

boils down to:

```
return UserDetailsConfirmation();
```

Comment: only validations are performed yes/cancel and pop up window are not performed

Comment: Don't care what comes before. You can NEVER get past the line "return confirm("Are you sure you want to add this ?");" and you only call the popup opener after that, i.e. NEVER.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function UserDetailsConfirmation() {
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to add this ?");
    if (r == true) {
       openwin();
    } else {
    return false;
    }
  }

function openwin() {
   window.open('PopupForConfirm.aspx?name1=' + name + '&age1=' + age + '&gen=' + gender + '', 'open_window', ' width=640, height=480, left=0, top=0');
}
function validate() {

    var name= document.getElementById('<%=this.txtname.ClientID %>');
    var age= document.getElementById('<%=this.txtage.ClientID %>');
    var gender= document.getElementById('<%=this.txtgender.ClientID %>');

    if (name.value) == "") {
        alert("Please Enter Name");
        name.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if (age.value) == "") {
        alert("Please Enter age");
        age.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if (gender.value) == "") {
    alert("Please enter gender");
    gender.focus();
    return false;
    }

else if (!UserDetailsConfirmation()) {
    return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

I have changed your code a bit ... While opening a popup return is not needed
I think this is enough to work

Comment: but am not getting my pop up window open

Comment: function openwin() {
   window.open("PopupForConfirm.aspx?name1=" + name + "&age1=" + age + "&gen=" + gender, "Popup", "toolbar=no, location=no,status=yes,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no, width=900,height=500,left=430,top=100");
return false;
}

Comment: try this @BeginnerStack1

Comment: again getting the same problem no pop up window shoot up

Comment: @BeginnerStack1 plz open the page in chrome browser and the click f12 and the again refresh it. then clcik on the button.. if there is any problem and error will show ..

Comment: I am not getting any error its just the pop up window not fired on submit.. I am getting only the confirmation.. even i tried in chrome as you said.. is there any other option for displaying this pop up window once i get my confirmation box

Comment: you can download firebug for mozilla..... and then u can debug it clearly .. once aftr installing.. u can click f12 is activate firebug

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your onclick, call UserDetailsConfirmation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function UserDetailsConfirmation() {
    if(validate() == true)
    {
        var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to add this ?");
        if (r == true) {
            openwin();
        }
    } else {
        alert('Something went wrong');
    }
  }

function openwin() {
   window.open('PopupForConfirm.aspx?name1=' + name + '&age1=' + age + '&gen=' + gender + '', 'open_window', ' width=640, height=480, left=0, top=0');
}
function validate() {

    var name= document.getElementById('<%=this.txtname.ClientID %>');
    var age= document.getElementById('<%=this.txtage.ClientID %>');
    var gender= document.getElementById('<%=this.txtgender.ClientID %>');

    if (name.value) == "") {
        alert("Please Enter Name");
        name.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if (age.value) == "") {
        alert("Please Enter age");
        age.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if (gender.value) == "") {
        alert("Please enter gender");
        gender.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

**Edited Option 2**

This is actually based on your code..

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function UserDetailsConfirmation() {
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to add this ?");
}

function openwin() {
   window.open('PopupForConfirm.aspx?name1=' + name + '&age1=' + age + '&gen=' + gender + '', 'open_window', ' width=640, height=480, left=0, top=0');
}
function validate() {

    var name= document.getElementById('<%=this.txtname.ClientID %>');
    var age= document.getElementById('<%=this.txtage.ClientID %>');
    var gender= document.getElementById('<%=this.txtgender.ClientID %>');

    if (name.value) == "") {
        alert("Please Enter Name");
        name.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if (age.value) == "") {
        alert("Please Enter age");
        age.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if (gender.value) == "") {
        alert("Please enter gender");
        gender.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if (UserDetailsConfirmation() == true) {
        openwin();
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: where am I suppose to call UserDetailsConfirmation()??

Comment: onclick event of your button

Comment: <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" Text="SUBMIT" onclick="btnsubmit_Click" OnClientClick="return validate();return UserDetailsConfirmation();" />   It is firing only the first function

Comment: <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" Text="SUBMIT" onclick="btnsubmit_Click" OnClientClick="return UserDetailsConfirmation();" />

Comment: I think the problem is with my pop up script because it is not getting fired

Comment: check your first parameter on your window.open. it seems that it does not take it as a landing URL